# Narrowing sql query

Tags: sql, limit

I am trying to be more specific on my query as you can see (link to image below) from the cupID column there is groups A to H 3 times. All I am trying to do is have 3 queries, first query to output all groups A-H only once, second query from the second and third from the third if that makes sense?

This is the query

```
SELECT cupID, date, matchno,
                    clan1,
                    clan2,
                    si
FROM ws_bi2_cup_matches
WHERE ladID='0'
  AND matchno = '6'
  AND TYPE = 'gs'
GROUP BY clan1
ORDER BY cupID ASC
```

which shows: (take a look at picture)
http://s13.postimg.org/6rufgywcn/image.png

so query 1/2/3 should output separately like (a,b,c,d etc) instead of 1 query showing multiples (aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd etc)

Many thanks for help

Comment: You  are grouping by `clan1`, yet have many other columns in the `select` clause.  This is not going to do what you expect.  Can you provide sample output of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that you are performing a union all on your 3 queries, please add a dummy column viz SortOrder and order by on it.

In the following sample query (SQL Server), I assumed all 3 queries as same, please do change them accordingly with the dummy sortorder:

```
   -- 1st query 
   SELECT cupID, date, matchno,
                       clan1,
                       clan2,
                       si,
                       1 as SortOrder -- dummy sort column 
   FROM ws_bi2_cup_matches
   WHERE ladID='0'
     AND matchno = '6'
     AND TYPE = 'gs'
   GROUP BY clan1

  union all 

   -- 2nd query 
   SELECT cupID, date, matchno,
                       clan1,
                       clan2,
                       si,
                       2 as SortOrder -- dummy sort column 
   FROM ws_bi2_cup_matches
   WHERE ladID='0'
     AND matchno = '6'
     AND TYPE = 'gs'
   GROUP BY clan1

  union all 

   -- 3rd query 
   SELECT cupID, date, matchno,
                       clan1,
                       clan2,
                       si,
                       3 as SortOrder -- dummy sort column 
   FROM ws_bi2_cup_matches
   WHERE ladID='0'
     AND matchno = '6'
     AND TYPE = 'gs'
   GROUP BY clan1

 order by 7 -- dummy sort order column
```